# Pattern Matching with DateTime.MinValue?

Tags: f#

I am writing an F# service that uses [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to poll another service (that has been written in C#):

```
[<PersistJobDataAfterExecution>]
[<DisallowConcurrentExecution>]
type PollingJob() = 
    interface IJob with 
        member x.Execute(context: IJobExecutionContext) = 
           let uri = "http://localhost:8089/"
           let storedDate = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetDateTime("LastPoll") 
           //this works...
           let effectiveFrom = (if storedDate = DateTime.MinValue then System.Nullable() else System.Nullable(storedDate))

           let result = someFunction uri effectiveFrom

           context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("LastPoll", DateTime.UtcNow) |> ignore
```

The `context` is passed to the `Execute` function by Quartz for every poll and contains a dictionary. The first time the service runs the value for `LastPoll` will be the default `DateTime` value i.e. `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. Then the next time the scheduler runs `LastPoll` will contain the time of the last poll.

I can create a `Nullable<DateTime>` using the `if..then..else` construct (above) but when I try to use pattern matching I get a compiler error with a squiggly under `DateTime.MinValue`:

> This field is not a literal and cannot be used in a pattern

The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
//this doesn't...
let effectiveFrom = 
    match storedDate with 
    | DateTime.MinValue -> System.Nullable()
    | _ -> System.Nullable(storedDate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using pattern matching slightly incorrectly.

The below should work:

```
    let effectiveFrom = 
        match storedDate with 
        | d when d = DateTime.MinValue -> System.Nullable()
        | _                            -> System.Nullable(storedDate)
```

When you want to test equality as part of a pattern match, you need to use a when clause (see here - https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/)

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. And thank you for the link.