# Pattern match multiple dates

Tags: f#

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888254/pattern-matching-with-datetime-minvalue/40888403), I can match against `DateTime.MinValue` like this:

```ml
let result = 
  match date with 
  | d when d = DateTime.MinValue -> 1
  | _                            -> 0
```

How do I do this, if I have a match like this?

```ml
let result = 
  match (startDate, endDate) with
```

This doesn't work:

```ml
let result = 
  match (startDate, endDate) with 
  | d when d = DateTime.MinValue, e when e = DateTime.MinValue  -> 0
```

Compiler error for the second `when`:

```
Unexpected keyword 'when' in pattern matching. Expected '->' or other token.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`when` can be added to a whole pattern, not to nested patterns, so you need something like this:

```ml
match (startDate, endDate) with
| d, e when d = DateTime.MinValue && e = DateTime.MinValue -> 0
| _ -> 1
```

Note that in this case, pattern matching is not really necessary, and you can go for a simpler if:

```ml
if d = DateTime.MinValue && e = DateTime.MinValue then
    0
else
    1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. For the second part of the answer: my pattern has at least for cases - that's why I wanted to use a pattern match instead of a nested `if ... then ... else ...`

Comment: for = four of course

Answer (score 4):

A possible alternative might be a partial active pattern, by moving part of the logic into it. The rule is matched when all tupled patterns are matched, and a partial active pattern is matched when it returns a `Some` value.

The partial active pattern here is of type `DateTime -> unit option`, as we going to ignore the return value anyway.

```
let (|IsMinValue|_|) d =
    if d = DateTime.MinValue then Some() else None
    
match startDate, endDate with
| IsMinValue, IsMinValue -> 0
| _ -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would use a partial active pattern. But i would add arguments to the pattern that makes it more re-usable.

```
let (|IsEqual|_|) shouldBe actual =
    if actual = shouldBe then Some actual else None

let isMinDate startDate endDate =
    match startDate, endDate with
    | IsEqual DateTime.MinValue d, IsEqual DateTime.MinValue e -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```